# I have 3 issues revolving around the styling of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 issues I would like help with.

**Issue 1.**

I have a navigation bar with numerous elements inside of it. The div with the ID `shopcartbar` will display the the div with ID `shoppingTab` once it is hovered over. I did initially set a `onmouseout` on the `shopcartbar` div but then when I tried to move the cursor on to the `shoppingTab` div, it would disappear. I would like to be able to keep the `shoppingTab` div visible whilst hovering over either of these divs and for the `onmouseout` to work on either of these as well, or at least be able to hover from the `shopcartbar` div on to the `shoppingTab` div to keep it visible because right now it disappears as there is a tiny gap between the two which even when I used CSS to close, didn't fix the problem. Before you read the code and say that I have set it to constantly be fixed on the page, I intentionally set it to have no `onmouseout` event otherwise it would vanish as soon as I moved my cursor therefore for debugging purposes, I made it appear permanently forcing me to refresh the page every time I wanted it gone.

**Issue 2**

When I set the height of the `shoppingTab` div to 100%, it only covers the span tags within it and not the 9 divs just underneath those tags, leaving the content overflowing out of the div. So I want the `shoppingTab` div to actually extend with ALL of the content and not just stop after the span tags. Please note: the amount of content changes so it can't be a fixed pixel height or percentage.

**Issue 3**

I have a cookie that just places the user's name in the `topnavbar` div which is placed before the `shopcartbar` div. When I hover over the `shopcartbar` div to show the `shoppingTab` div, it makes the persons name disappear whilst leaving the text inside the `shopcartbar` div. I would like the text from the `topnavbar` div to remain as well even when the `shoppingTab` div is displayed upon hover. Please note: the persons name must be placed before the `shopcartbar`div.

Here is the HTML that contains everything needed to solve the 3 issues.

```css
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */

    body{ /* Applies to the <body> tag */
        margin:0px; /* Sets the margin on all sides to 0px */
    }
    .container{ /* The container class */
        width:100%; /* This sets the width */
        height:100%; /* This sets the height */
        background-color:black; /* Sets the background colour */
        font-family:"Myriad Pro"; /* Sets the font family */
    }
    .header{ /* The header class */
        width:100%;
        background-color:#323232;
        color:white; /* The sets the colour of the font */
    }
    .body{
        width:100%;
        height:1100px;
        background-color:white;
        color:black;
        text-align:center; /* Determines the positioning of the text alignment */
    }
    .footer{
        width:100%;
        height:50px;
        background-color:#323232;
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
    }
    div{
        display: inline-block; /* Sets the display type */
        float:left; /* Sets the float position */
    }
    #one, #two, #three, #four{
        background-color:#323232;
        height:90px;
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:25px;
    }
    #slider{
        background-color:#ed1c24;
        height:10px;
        width:100px;
        position: absolute; /* Sets the position to a specific type */
        left: 0; /* Sets the number of pixels from the left that this object is placed */
        bottom:0; /* Sets the number of pixels from the bottom that this object is placed */
    }
    .inside{
        margin-left:30px; /* Specifies the margin from the left side */
        margin-right:30px; /* Specifies the margin from the right side */
        padding-top:7px; /* Specifies the padding from the top side */
        pointer-events:none; /* Specifies the cursor events */
        margin-top:25px; /* Specifies the margin from the top side */
    }
    .button{
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 4px; /* Specifies the radius of each corner */
        background-color: #ed1c24;
        border:none; /* Specifies the border type */
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 28px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 200px;
        transition: all 0.5s; /* Specifies the the interval over which an animation occurs */
        cursor: pointer; /* Specifies the cursor type */
        margin: 5px;
        height:60px;
    }

    .button span{
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .button span:after{
        content: '»'; /* Specifies the content of the div */
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0; /* Specifies the opacity or transparency level */
        top: 0; /* Specifies the distance from the top */
        right: -20px; /* Specifies the distance from the right */
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .button:hover span{
        padding-right: 25px;
    }

    .button:hover span:after{
        opacity: 1;
        right: 0;
    }
    #cover{
        position:fixed; 
        top:0; 
        left:0; 
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
        z-index:5; 
        width:100%; 
        height:100%; 
        display:block;
    }
    #loginScreen{ 
        height:300px; 
        width:400px; 
        z-index:10; 
        background-color:white; 
        no-repeat; border:7px solid #cccccc; 
        border-radius:10px;
        margin-left:35%;
        margin-top:12%;
        position:relative;
        padding-top:10px;
        font-family:"Myriad Pro";
        font-size:18px;
    }
    .cancel{ 
        display:block; 
        position:absolute; 
        top:3px; 
        right:2px; 
        background:rgb(245,245,245); 
        color:black; 
        height:32px; 
        width:32px; 
        font-size:30px; 
        text-decoration:none; 
        text-align:center; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        border-radius:36px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    p1{
        font-style: italic;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }
    p1:before, p1:after{
        background-color: #000;
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        height: 1px;
        position: relative;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 40%;
    }
    p1:before{
        right: 0.5em;
        margin-left: -50%;
    }
    p1:after{
        left: 0.5em;
        margin-right: -50%;
    }
    #searchbar{
        background:url(../images/searchbarbg.png) no-repeat scroll;
        padding-left:30px;
        height:24px;
        width:180px;
        border-radius:36px;
    }
    .product{
        height:290px;
        width:200px;
        float:left;
        border: 5px solid black;
        border-radius:10px;
        margin-left:3%;
        margin-top:3%;
        font-size:16px;
        text-align:center;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .product:hover{
        border:5px solid #ed1c24;
    }
    table{
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table, td, th{
        border: 0px solid black;
    }
    #shoppingTab{
        display:none;
        height:670px;
        width:400px;
        background-color:white;
        color:black;
        position:relative;
        margin-top:-2px;
        border-radius:10px;
        color:black;
        border:1px solid #323232;
        padding:10px;
        float:right;
        z-index:50;
    }
    .plusbutton{
        height:25px;
        width:25px;
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color:#323232;
        float:left;
        border-radius:5px 0px 0px 5px;
        color:white;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .minusbutton{
        height:25px;
        width:25px;
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color:#323232;
        float:left;
        border-radius:0px 5px 5px 0px;
        color:white;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .quantityBox{
        height:23px;
        width:25px;
        border-top:1px solid black;
        border-bottom:1px solid black;
        background-color:white;
        float:left;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:24px;
    }
    .smallProduct{
        height:50px;
        width:390px;
        float:left;
        border: 5px solid black;
        border-radius:10px;
        font-size:16px;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .smallProduct:hover{
        border:5px solid #ed1c24;
    }

    /* #ed1c24 is red, #323232 is grey */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:right; font-family:'Myriad Pro'; background-image:url(images/loginsignupbar.png); width:535.1px; height:30px">
                <div onmouseover="document.getElementById('shoppingTab').style.display='block';" id="shopcartbar" style="float:right; font-size:24px; margin-top:-7px">
                <img src="images/shoppingCart.png" height="30px"/>&nbsp;Shopping Cart (<span id="numberOfItems">0</span>)&nbsp;
                </div>
                <div id="shoppingTab">
                Shopping Cart<br />
                    <div class="smallProduct" style="margin-top:5px" id="thmbproduct0"></div>
                    <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct1"></div>
                    <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct2"></div>
                    <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct3"></div>
                    <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct4"></div>
                    <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct5"></div>
                    <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct6"></div>
                    <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct7"></div>
                    <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct8"></div>
                    Total: $<span id="totalPrice">00</span>.00
                </div>
                <span id="topnavbar" style="float:right; font-size:24px; margin-top:5.5px">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; clear:right"> <!-- This is the navigation menu -->
                <div style="position:relative"> <!-- This is the container of the navigation menu -->
                    <div id="slider"></div> <!-- This is the slider bar -->
                    <a href="index.html"><div id="one" class="item"><div class="inside">Home</div></div></a> <!-- This is just one of the buttons -->
                    <a href="about.html"><div id="two" class="item"><div class="inside">About Us</div></div></a>
                    <a href="shop.html"><div id="three" class="item"><div class="inside">Shop</div></div></a>
                    <a href="contact.html"><div id="four" class="item"><div class="inside">Contact</div></div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body"> <!-- This is the body --><br />
            <span style="font-size:50px">Welcome to the store.</span><br />
            <table width="90%" style="margin-left:5%; margin-bottom:2%">
              <tr>
                <td style="width:20%; border-right:solid black 1px; border-bottom:solid black 1px"><b>Search Tools</b></td>
                <td style="border-bottom:solid black 1px"><b>Products</b></td>
                <td style="border-bottom:solid black 1px"><span style="float:right; margin-bottom:1%">Search for products... <span style="color:#666"><i>(e.g. Mirage Sedan)</i></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="searchbar" onkeyup="searchProducts(this.value)"/></span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="border-right:solid black 1px; padding-top:3%" valign="top">
                <b>Sort Type:</b><br /><br />
                <select id="sortType">
                <option value="AtoZ">A to Z</option>
                <option value="ZtoA">Z to A</option>
                <option value="LowtoHigh">Price (low to high)</option>
                <option value="HightoLow">Price (high to low)</option>
                </select>
                <br /><br /><form><b>Price range:</b><br /><br /><input id="priceRange" step="100" value="42000" min="12000" max="42000" type="range"/><div id="rangeVal">0</div><br /><br /><b>Model Type:</b><br /><br /><input type="radio" name="model"/>Car<br /><input type="radio" name="model"/>SUV</form></td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="product" id="product0"></div>
                    <div class="product" id="product1"></div>
                    <div class="product" id="product2"></div>
                    <div class="product" id="product3"></div>
                    <div class="product" id="product4"></div>
                    <div class="product" id="product5"></div>
                    <div class="product" id="product6"></div>
                    <div class="product" id="product7"></div>
                    <div class="product" id="product8"></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"> <!-- This is the footer -->
        <br />This is the footer</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cover">
        <div id="loginScreen">
            <center id="content"><br />
            <span style="font-size:45px" id="popuptitle">Welcome!</span><br />
            <span id="popupdescription">Please log in or sign up.</span><br />
                <button class="button" style="font-size:20px; height:45px; width:150px; margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:15px" onclick="logInMenu()"><span>Log In</span></button><br /><p1>OR</p1><br />
                <button class="button" style="font-size:20px; height:45px; width:150px; margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:15px" onclick="signUpMenu()"><span>Sign Up</span></button>
            </center>
            <a onclick="document.getElementById('cover').style.display = 'none'" class="cancel">&times;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Desired functionality for issue 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
}
.header{
    width:960px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#06F;
    float:left;
}
.trolley{
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:white;
    float:right;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:black;
    border:1px solid black;
    line-height:30px;
    font-family:"Calibri";
    cursor: pointer;
}
.shop{
    width:960px;
    height:700px;
    background-color:white;
    float:left;
    font-family:"Calibri Light";
    padding:20px;
}
#shoppingTab{
    display:none;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:1px;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:black;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding-left:10px;
    float:right;
}
html{
    background-color:#00F;
}
.product{
    height:200px;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-right:20px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.product:hover{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <span id="name"></span><div class="trolley" onmouseover="tabDisplay('block')" onmouseout="tabDisplay('none')"><center>Shopping Cart <span style='font-family:webdings'>&#164;</span> <span id="NOI" style="background-color:red; border-radius:360px; color:white; padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px">0</span></center>
            <div id="shoppingTab">You have selected <span id="NOI2">0</span> items. Your total is $<span id="totalPrice">0</span><br/><span id="itemsList"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop" style="font-size:28px">Welcome, <span id="name2"></span>.<hr /><br/>Products<br/><hr />

    <div class="product" onclick="addToCart('sunglasses', 0, 70)">Pair of sunglasses ($70)<br /><br /><span onclick="change(1)">Click to add to cart</span></div>
    <div class="product" onclick="addToCart('shoes', 1, 180)">Pair of shoes ($180)<br /><br /><span onclick="change(3)">Click to add to cart</span></div>
    <div class="product" onclick="addToCart('belt', 2, 20)">A belt ($20)<br /><br /><span onclick="change(3)">Click to add to cart</span></div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var customerName = "";
var numberOfItems = 0;
var total = 0;
var items = [];
var stat = []

for(var a = 1; a <= 3; a++){
    stat[a] = false;
}

function update(){
    document.getElementById("NOI").innerHTML = numberOfItems;
    document.getElementById("NOI2").innerHTML = numberOfItems;
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = total;
    document.getElementById("itemsList").innerHTML = items.join("<br />");
}
function tabDisplay(displayStatus){
    shoppingTab.style.display = displayStatus;
}

function addToCart(productName, productID, price){
    items[productID] = productName;
    total += price;
    numberOfItems++;
    update();
}

function removeFromCart(productName, productID, price){
    items.splice(productID, 1);
    total -= price;
    if(stat[productID]){
    numberOfItems--;
    }
    update();
}

function change(i){
    if(stat[i] == false){
        stat[i] = true;
    }else{
        stat[i] = false;
    }
}

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("customer");
    if (user != "") {
        customerName = getCookie("customer");
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = customerName;
        alert("Welcome again, " + user + ".");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "please set up an account";
       user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("customer", user, 30);
           document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = user;
       }
    }
}

function changeCookie(){
    var user = getCookie("customer");
    user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("customer", user, 30);
       }
       document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = user;
}
checkCookie();
</script>
```

Comment: You have a lot of text/code in your question, is there any chance of cutting it down to make it easier?

Comment: Also, if you have **multiple** questions then you shuld ask **each one separately**.

Comment: The functionality is kind of essential and it is all mostly important, I apologise because you are right it is very large.

Comment: I would have asked them in separate questions but they are all concerning that one same div and the three questions may be able to be solved simultaneously.

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian please feel free to look at this question :)

Answer (score 0):

For issue 1, you could try a setTimeout() function in the onmouseout() function linking to the actual code (to make it disappear) with a delay (in milliseconds e.g: 500)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

If it doesn't work, try putting both `shoppingtab` and `shopcartbar` in a single div and use `onmouseover` of that div to display and hide `shoppingTab`

Comment: No offence but I would like to be accurate. Maybe something like this separate prototype I built. Look in the original question at the base where under the heading desired functionality for issue 1.

Comment: sorry , i'm only a newbie

Comment: You can use onmouseout().hide(slow); it let you time to set a onmouseon().show(fast); on your div.

Comment: Nah its okay @MarkPerera - Your input is still appreciated!